# Flutter - Overridden dependencies

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

**After running "flutter pub get", I got this error:**

> **Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:**
>
> **! path 1.6.4**

Comment: attach your pubspec.yaml files code with your question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's not an issue. That happens because you (or any other transitive dependency) may be overriding some dependency that you are already using. For example, if you are using `path: 0.X.X` and some other dependency use `dependency_overrides` to make sure that is using `path: 1.6.4`, it will present you that message.

Overall, you shouldn't have to worry with that and sometimes it is actually required in order to some dependencies work all together.

Comment: What's the solution?

Answer (score 5):

Please give more details so that i can answer it better. **Attach your pubspec.yaml**.

But now i can tell you some methods which should work..
first of all see if you are using the **latest version of all dependencies** or not then:

try:

- **restarting your ide**
- `flutter clean`

if these two don't work then at last try

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same error after cloning a flutter repository. I initially mistook the error for being a build issue when it's just a warning that won't stop your app from running.

I solved the build issue I was having with the freshly cloned project by running this command inside the app's root directory: `flutter pub run build_runner build`

Comment: When I run this, I get `Could not find package "build_runner". Did you forget to add a dependency?`

Comment: @Ky- Try flutter pub get after